# How to remove sub-menu border from the menu list

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the border that I have under the sub menu -"View All clients", "Add New Clients". any help would be really appreciated. The picture is attached here has the menu and sub-menu that I want to remove the border  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKLgZ.png

```css
.help-left-menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 36px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.help-left-menu li {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: rgba(119, 140, 162, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.help-left-menu li {
  list-style: none;
}

#dropdown-items {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 2px;
}

#dropdown-items a {
  color: white;
}

.menu {
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-list li a.active {
  background: darkslategray;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none
}

.config-left {
  margin-top: 36px;
}

.content-heading {
  background-color: rgba(119, 140, 162, 1);
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  color: white;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.features {
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="help-left-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-list">
    <div class="features">
      <h5>FEATURES</h5>
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dashboard-content" class="dashboard menu 
               tab">DASHBOARD<i class="dropdown-icon"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-list"><a href="#" data-toggle="new-proposal- 
     content" class="newProposal menu tab">NEW PROPOSAL<i class="dropdown- 
     icon"></i></a></li>

  <li class="dropdown-list"><a href="#" data-toggle="proposal-content" class="proposal menu tab">PROPOSALS<i class="dropdown-icon"></i></a>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown-list"><a href="#" data-toggle="client- 
           content" class="clients menu">CLIENTS<i class="dropdown-icon"></i>
        
                 <ul class="submenu" id="dropdown-items">
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="view-all-client-content" 
           class="view-allClients submenu tab">View All Clients</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="add-new-client-content" class="add- 
    newClient submenu tab">Add New Clients</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Kindly post the code, so that it will be easy for us to look into the issue and help you out.

Comment: @Manjuboyz the code has been added. Can you please help me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```css
.help-left-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.submenu li {
  border: 0;
}

.submenu a {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="help-left-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-list">
    <div class="features">
      <h5>FEATURES</h5>
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dashboard-content" class="dashboard menu 
               tab">DASHBOARD<i class="dropdown-icon"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-list"><a href="#" data-toggle="new-proposal- 
     content" class="newProposal menu tab">NEW PROPOSAL<i class="dropdown- 
     icon"></i></a></li>

  <li class="dropdown-list"><a href="#" data-toggle="proposal-content" class="proposal menu tab">PROPOSALS<i class="dropdown-icon"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-list"><a href="#" data-toggle="client- 
           content" class="clients menu">CLIENTS<i class="dropdown-icon"></i>
        
                 <ul class="submenu" id="dropdown-items">
              <li><a href="#" data-toggle="view-all-client-content" 
           class="view-allClients submenu tab">View All Clients</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="add-new-client-content" class="add- 
    newClient submenu tab">Add New Clients</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the code hass been added. can you please help me now. I have edited the post. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MdEasirArafat I have updated my answer, there are some issues with code as well, have fixed that as well.

Comment: .help-left-menu i have adde the css     .help-left-menu li { border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC that is why your solution is not working here. What else can I do now? Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @MdEasirArafat updated my answer, hope this is what you need.

Comment: sir, added the css code.  Can you please have a look at the edited code above and give me a solution.

Comment: Your code has worked fine. Thank you so much for heaping me sir. I appreciate  your help and support. There is javascript added for opening the submenu. that is why it is not opening. @Manjuboyz

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `border: none` in your CSS selector, make sure to try adding `!important` or adding a higher specificity to it in case anything has higher specificity than it.